# Count clicked checkboxes, even after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I am trying to keep count of how many times the check boxes have been clicked on my site, the check boxes are used for filters (for men, women, age, etc).
At the moment I have this code

```
jQuery('[id^="checkbox"] input').each(
    function (index, element) {
        jQuery(this).click(
            function () {
                console.debug("Hello");
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Which will count (in console) how many times a check box has been click (with an id starting with checkbox), but because the page refreshes the information (and url) with each click, it will only count the first click, and the rest will not be counted. 
Is there anyway to carry on counting after the page has been refreshed? 
Thanks

Comment: What do you want to do with click counter? Answer depends on this

Comment: To log the information. there are ~15 different checkboxes (all that start with the id "checkbox". The information will be logged. I am currently testing out the answers to see if they work.

Comment: If you want to log clicks for yourself (not for users), you may send an ajax query to your server when checkbox is clicked, and count clicks on backend. But, you should make sure that page will reload after an ajax call, or it (ajax call) will be aborted.

Comment: I have been looking at using ajaxComplete, but have not had any luck with that. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nrLpxLuf/ look in console to see how it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have a persistent count of all checkboxes being checked across all users, you need to have a central total which all counts update. This will be quite tricky for even large sites like YouTube still struggle with this (although to a lesser extent).

I am unaware that this can be accomplished purely in JS (if anyone knows, please edit this answer) and you will likely need some sort of back-end code.

One approach you could take would be:

1. update a local total of checked checkboxes on click
2. set a timer of 1/2 seconds on click
3. once the timer ends, send an ajax request to a back-end page
4. back-end page receives the update, update the central total

There are many other approaches you could take. You're likely to run into issues like, the central total might not be very accurate (if ajax requests are interrupted) and your bandwidth usage increasing due to the ajax requests.

---

[Gennady Dogaev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2948109/gennady-dogaev) shared some really good code which posts the id of the checkbox and it's value to another page. This page would likely have the logic to update a database or something similar to track which checkboxes are being used.

> ```
> <body>
>     <input type="checkbox" id="check_1" /> 1
>     <input type="checkbox" id="check_2" /> 2
>     <input type="checkbox" id="check_3" /> 3
> </body>
>
>
> $(function(){
>     $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
>         var box = $(this);
>         var data = {
>             id: box.prop('id'),
>             checked: box.is(':checked')
>         };
>         $.get('https://stackoverflow.com/', data).always(function(response){
>             console.log('server responded', response);
>             /*Click registered, do what you want here*/
>         });
>     });
> });
> ```
>
> https://jsfiddle.net/nrLpxLuf/

---

The below answer was to help count all checked checkboxes on the page and update the total locally. I've left it here for reference.

> You don't need to loop over all elements to attach a single click event to all of them.
>
> Instead attach a click event to a collection of checkboxes and then update a total variable from within the click function.
>
> ```
> var $inputs = $('[id^="checkbox"] input');
> var total = $inputs.filter(':checked').length; //this will be 0 if none are found
>
> $inputs.on('click', function(event) {
>   if($(this).is(':checked')) {
>      total++;
>   } else {
>      total--;
>   }
>
>   console.log(total);
> });
> ```
>
> If you only want to see if it has been clicked, just add to the total.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but where can this information be logged? Thank you

Comment: I've updated my answer. We need a bit more information to help you.

Comment: The total will be shared across all users, the aim of this is to see which check boxes are being click on more, which are being ignored etc.

Comment: I've updated my answer to try and point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for all the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set value on load if you want to count the checked after refresh.

```
var total = 0;
$(document).ready(function (event) {
    //onload count for the checked checkboxes and set total value
    total = $('[id^="checkbox"] input:checked').length;
    $('[id^="checkbox"] input').on('click', function (event) {
        $(this).prop('checked') ? total++ :total--;
    });
});
```